# Emitting multiple times

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've read through the site and googled, and can't seem to find an answer that will work for me.

I've set up a super super basic example of using Socket.IO until I can get my head around, all it does is passes a number to the back end, adds +1 and send it back to front end.

It does work however, each interval round, it emits more and more (which I can see using console.log on the server side.) I'm only connected using one computer to test.

Can someone help me please. I understand its probably because the emit is inside the connection but I just can't quite click in my head on how to overcome this.

I've tried moving bits around, moving the function out of the connection. I've tried multiple ideas from google, but nothing seems to solve it.

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('subscribeToAddition', (additon,interval) => {
    console.log('current number... ', additon);
    setInterval(() => {
      socket.emit('addition', additon+1);
    }, interval);
  });
});

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

the interval variable is set as 5 seconds in my react component. I just want it to log/update once every five seconds instead of log once, then twice, then 4 times, then 8 times, etc

Comment: I don't know what your React component looks like, but considering the amount is doubling every time my guess is that you're re-subscribing to the event every time you receive the emitted `addition` event.

Comment: Perfect use case of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `setInterval` schedules _an infinite number of calls spaced at almost-fixed intervals_ so the first time `subscribeToAddition` registers, [you schedule an infinite number of calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/setInterval). Then the second time, you _add_ an infinite number of calls. Then the third time you add _even more_ calls. I'm pretty sure what you actually wanted, given your description, is [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the symptoms, it's likely that you're sending the `subscribeToAddition` event more than once on the same socket and thus starting more than one timer for the same socket and thus you get duplicate messages.

---

Proper indentation of your code makes things a little clearer:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('subscribeToAddition', (additon, interval) => {

        console.log('current number... ', additon);

        setInterval(() => {
            socket.emit('addition', additon + 1);
        }, interval);

    });

});

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

I want to make sure you understand that `setInterval()` starts a repeating timer that goes forever until you call `clearInterval()` on the timerId that it returns.

Problems I see:

1. In every `subscribeToAddition` message, you're adding a new `setInterval()` timer.  So, if you send the `subscribeToAddition` twice, you will have two `setInterval()` timers each going on the same socket.
2. Those `setInterval()` timers will accumulate and never go away because you have no way of the client stopping them and they don't go away even when the socket closes.  They will just cause errors because `socket.emit()` won't work on a closed socket, but they will probably even prevent garbage collection of the old socket.

---

It is not clear exactly how you want this to work, but here's a cleaned up version:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    function clearTimer() {
        if (socket.myTimer) {
            clearInterval(socket.myTimer);
            delete socket.myTimer;
        }
    }

    socket.on('subscribeToAddition', (additon, interval) => {

        console.log('current number... ', additon);

        // don't start a new interval timer if one is already running
        if (!socket.mytimer) {

            socket.mytimer = setInterval(() => {
                socket.emit('addition', ++additon);
            }, interval);
        }

    });

    socket.on('unSubscribeToAddition', () => {
        clearTimer();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        clearTimer();
    });

});

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

This version makes the following modifications:

1. Keeps track of the timerID from `setInterval()` so we can stop it in the future.  For convenience, we store it as a custom property on the socket object so that each connected socket has its own timer.
2. Adds an `unsubscribeToAddition` message so the client can stop the timer.
3. Adds a `disconnect` message handler so you can stop the timer when the socket disconnects.
4. Increments the `additon` variable on each tick of the timer.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Yeah it's easier to see when the code is clean... :) Every day's a school day! Thanks again.